# Console freezing via ssh to remote server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

When I try to connect to remote server I have problems with freezing in console. I have to wait from 5 to 30+ seconds between each of command. I use openssh as vpn client for connect to this server.

The problem occurs only with this server. Connections to others server are good and without freezing.

[image]

The last 30 seconds on the gif the command "cat" just hung

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: Open a second terminal and have it pinging that host. Connect with `ssh -vvv` for more verbosity. That might tell you if it's just a network issue. Also consider running a third terminal, ssh'd into that host, with `top` running to see if it's a load issue on the server. Ask about this on a more appropriate Stack Exchange site like the above ones or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).